# Error when using a RasterBrick to running vifstep() from usdm in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, multicollinearity

I'm trying to use a RasterBrick to run the vifstep function from usdm in R and I'm getting the following error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = .dd[, i] ~ ., data = .dd[-i], drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :
> 'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list

```
class(pred.mask)
[1] "RasterBrick"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"

vif.step <- usdm::vifstep(pred.mask,
                          th = 5,
                          method = "pearson")
```

I was expecting that it would work since the function's help defines that the data can be "a raster object (RasterStack or RasterBrick or SpatRaster), or as a matrix, or as a data.frame."

Answer (score 0):

Update: I reached out to the package developer who advised I use a SpatRaster rather than a RasterStack so I converted using the terra::rast function and it worked thereafter...

Comment: Yes, but I'm using ENMeval, so I have to use a rasterStack. I'm trying to avoid so many conversions, but it seems to be the only solution, for now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Here, a demonstration that your suggestion works in a modification of OP's MRE would be helpful.